# how to change jquerymobile ui-blocks height and width

Tags: jquery-mobile

am using jquerymobile  for representing a two column radiobuttons in my project, the problem am facing is the contents of the block-a is lengther than the contents of the block-b so am getting a difference of div size the output is at (http://i40.tinypic.com/r0tt85.png) if u can lookat  my out put the second question 6th option is small when compare to all the other ones the block size is based on the content how can i make same size for all the blocks without based on the content any help please needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want all blocks to be the same height, you can set the height in CSS:

```
.ui-bar {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: the solution  u proposed was not working  can u give some other idea thank you for your reply can u look at this url for my output http://i40.tinypic.com/33my24h.png